# How to place randomly selected images from a database at random locations on a page?

Tags: php, image, random

I'm trying to display random images from a folder in random places on the page.

So far I've tried using php as I understand it is better suited to taking images randomly from larger databases. However I want to make the images draggable which I have achieved so far using javascript.

```
<?php
    $all_images = glob("/images/*.{jpeg|jpg|png|gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

    shuffle($all_images);

    list ($img1, $img2, $img3, $img4) = $all_images;
```

What is missing? Do I need to add an echo or a img_src?

Comment: just print `$img`, ... and see if there is anything in it. and paste the output.

Comment: no sure what you mean, it shows nothing if i place $img at the bottom of it

Answer (score 0):

You have to output the HTML `<img>` tag by using `echo` or `print`. In the following example, I am just looping over the shuffled images and outputting each one.

I should also make it clear that I am using a `foreach` loop since I don't know how many images are in that directory. It could be variable.

```
<?php
$all_images = glob("/images/*.{jpeg|jpg|png|gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

shuffle($all_images);

foreach ($all_images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
}
```

**EDIT**

> no images appear though, just '; } ?>

Are you sure PHP is enabled and working? Can you please confirm by replacing everything in your file with:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Do you see the output of your configuration?

If not, then you need to get your PHP interpreter going first. That is beyond the scope of this answer.

If you do, then something else is going on. I would remove all of your HTML tags and simply try to output the image paths first. Notice that I am using commas `,` instead of the the pipe `|` to separate the file extensions. Play around with this until you see a listing of your files. For example:

```
<?php
// Play around with this until you see output.
$all_images = glob("/images/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

var_dump($all_images);
```

Once you have that, then come back to my original solution to actually output the  tags.

Comment: <html lang="en-US">
<head>  
 <body>
 <?php
$all_images = glob("\images\*.{jpeg|jpg|png|gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

shuffle($all_images);

foreach ($all_images as $image) {
    print '<img src="'.$image.'">';
}
?>
 
 
</body></html>

Comment: thank you, I get a blank page from all php code input. I'm using Godaddy and it says php is enabled so I'm at a loss.